# Why is no Exception Being Thrown? (C#/NUnit/.NET 6)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit

I'm new to C#.

I am trying to test my controller but I am having trouble getting the tests to work. For this test, I want to throw an exception I created, InvalidQueryException. When I run the test, I get this message:

"Expected: <RedAeris.Exceptions.InvalidQueryException>
But was:  null"

Why is this occurring? I am suspecting that nothing is actually running because my break points or print statements don't work.

Below is controller and tests:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using RedAeris.Constants;
using RedAeris.Exceptions;
using RedAeris.Models;
using RedAeris.Utilities;
using System.Text.Json;

namespace RedAeris.Controllers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class is responsible for gathering data for symbols.
    /// </summary>
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TickerHistoryController : ControllerBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// This function is used to get data for a symbol based on a ticker query and return the returns for an investment.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tickerQuery"></param>
        /// <returns>Return the returns for a given investment.</returns>
        /// <exception cref="Exceptions.InvalidQueryException"></exception>
        // GET api/<TickerHistory>/tickerQuery?fromDate={yyyy-MM-dd}&toDate={yyyy-MM-dd}&tickerSymbol={SYMBOL}'
        [HttpGet("tickerQuery")]
        public async Task<List<double>> TickerData([FromQuery] TickerQuery tickerQuery)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HIT");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tickerQuery.tickerSymbol))
            {
                throw new InvalidQueryException(InvalidQueryException.MISSING_TICKER_SYMBOL_MESSAGE); // Can't perform search without a symbol
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tickerQuery.fromDate.ToString()))
            {
                tickerQuery.fromDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, 1, 1);
            }
            // toDate is missing
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tickerQuery.toDate.ToString()))
            {
                tickerQuery.toDate = DateTime.Today;
            }
            // Too long of query
            if ((tickerQuery.toDate - tickerQuery.fromDate).TotalDays > IEX.MAX_QUERY_TIMERANGE * IEX.DAYS_IN_YEAR)
            {
                throw new InvalidQueryException(InvalidQueryException.MAX_TIMERANGE_EXCEEDED_MESSAGE);
            }
            // Start time comes after end
            if ((tickerQuery.toDate - tickerQuery.fromDate).TotalDays < 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidQueryException(InvalidQueryException.INVALID_START_AND_END_DATE_COMBINATION_MESSAGE);
            }

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var url = IEX.urlBuilder(tickerQuery); // Creates URL for API call
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    string jsonData = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonData);
                    List<TickerData> data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<TickerData>>(jsonData); // Map JSON to TickerData list

                    return ReturnCalculator.calculateReturn(data);
                    
                }
                else
                {
                    return null;
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Test:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing;
using NUnit.Framework;
using RedAeris.Exceptions;


namespace RedAeris.Tests.Controllers
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TickerHistoryControllerTests
    {


        private WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
        }

        [TearDown]
        public void Teardown()
        {
            factory.Dispose();
        }


        [Test]
        public async Task ShouldThrowInvalidQueryExceptionWithNoTicker()
        {

            var client = factory.CreateClient();
            var url = "https://localhost:7267/api/TickerHistory/tickerQuery?fromDate=2023%2F04%2F01&toDate=2023%2F04%2F20";

            // Act & Assert
            Assert.ThrowsAsync<InvalidQueryException>(async () => await client.GetAsync(url));
            // Assert.AreEqual("Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).", exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Tests not running as expected

Comment: Was this intended to be a unit test? What you have here is an integration test. You're using the API over the HTTP channel. The exception becomes a 500 response, which isn't being translated back to an exception on the client side. Without that translation, the test you have requires that you use the controller class and call the method directly to observe that exception.

Comment: And as far as API contracts go, that exception is being thrown for a validation failure, which should be a 400 response (Bad Request), so you would need middleware that translates that kind of exception to a 400 response. The client would then need to translate 400 to the expected exception.

Comment: @madreflection Why am I getting null though? How should I go about testing input though? I don't want to create constructors just for testing. I would like to give example URL's and call the URL to see how the function behaves

Comment: You're not actually getting `null`. `Assert` is saying that the actual exception was no exception at all, which it indicates with `null`, apparently. That's because the exception thrown in the controller was caught by ASP.NET Core and translated to a 500 response with a ProblemDetails payload. `HttpClient` just sees a response body. It doesn't know that an exception caused it. `await client.GetAsync` will return an `HttpResponseMessage` so `Assert.ThrowsAsync` will fail that expectation every time.

Comment: *"call the URL to see how the function behaves"* - That's an integration test, and it shouldn't be used to test validation. That's what unit testing is for. Instantiate the controller, call the method directly, catch the exception.  *"I don't want to create constructors just for testing."* - You don't have to do that if you're using dependency injection, and using it properly. You're not. In fact, `using (var client = new HttpClient())` is *very bad*, and there's plenty of guidance out there on what you *should* do instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your `url` variable should be:

```
var url = "/api/TickerHistory/tickerQuery?fromDate=2023%2F04%2F01&toDate=2023%2F04%2F20";
```